# Hiding columns based on cell value in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets-macros

I have a dropdown list in cell "B3", containing numbers 1 through 18. 1 corresponds to column C, 2 to column D, 3 to Column E and 18 to column T. I want to achieve the following:

If I select 3 from the dropdown list, column "E" of columns C:T will be visible, if 7 is selected column "I" will be the only column displayed from columns C:T.

I have been unable to find vba codes that work. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Excel or Google Sheets?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try to be more specific about which program, coding language, framework or platform you are using, not only in tags but in your title as well

Answer (score 1):

Once you know how to read the value of the dropdown list (call it `x`), do following code:

```
Columns(,x + 2).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```